# Predicting Multi dependent variables

Tags: machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, recommender-system

**Data:**

```
transaction - product_bought,amount,time,date,Client_age,Client_occupation etc
product- 20 types (categorical)
```

If we want to predict by analyzing 1 year of transactions, what product user will buy next and when :

**To predict :**

```
Product , time ( in days after last transaction)
```

**Example:**

```
      |  Product   | When                             |
User1 |    Milk    | in 10 days from last transaction |
User2 |    Bread   | in 2 days from last transaction  |
```

what will be the best approach in this scenario ? 
should we train two different models ? 
or there is a better way, something like using collaborative filtering or PLS etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Anybody, exploring the same area, following papers helped me in solving this problem :

**A Dynamic Recurrent Model for Next Basket Recommendation**
http://www.nlpr.ia.ac.cn/english/irds/People/sw/DREAM.pdf

**Factorizing Personalized Markov Chains for Next-Basket Recommendation:**
https://www.ismll.uni-hildesheim.de/pub/pdfs/RendleFreudenthaler2010-FPMC.pdf

Comment: one more: 
Next Basket Prediction using Recurring Sequential Patterns:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.07158.pdf